# how to translate xfx and / or onomatopoeia of the one piece manga

Tags: translation, manga, onomatopoeia, sound-symbolism

[image: Image from one peace manga(E)89]

Does anyone know how to translate or any method to understand the xfx and / or onomatopoeia of the one piece manga?  If anyone knows please give me a hand.

Comment: This kind of sound https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIgT8Z5x9m8, http://soundeffect-lab.info/sound/battle/mp3/sword-clash4.mp3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find [The JADED Network](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/search/?keyword=%E3%82%AC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3&submitSearch=Search+SFX&x=) to be a good English glossary for Japanese onomatopoeia and mimetic words.  Normal Japanese-English dictionaries usually aren't enough to handle the diversity of manga sound effects.

If you don't find a word in there, try fiddling with long vowels or small "っ"s a bit.  In this case, I've shortened ガキイン *Claang* to ガキン *Clang*, and found it.

Comment: Can you give help me translating other symbols like this? i mean when i try to do it..."Returned 0 Results for ガボーン"  this shows up

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be missing that one. To me at least ガボーン sounds like an explosion, like English *kaboom*. If there are no explosions happening in this part of the story, keep in mind that the author Oda likes to draw onomatopoeias just to make the manga feel cool and dramatic (for example, you must surely have noticed all the random ドーンs he uses).

Comment: hmm ok, :) many thanks you are right its like an explosion but emotional one...like a big surprise or exaggeration or exaltation

Answer (score 0):

It is sound ガキイン, four texts, one by one read as "ga,ki,i,n". It sound like means slash on target.
Read it fast, you will know the result of sound given by these onomatopoeia.
At left side, small ハア、ハア is "haa", is a whispering sound haa~ haa~, repiration sound, tired sound.